# Stuck at global import in Python

Tags: python

I have a `message.py` file:

```
def error(message):
    print(f"\033[91m{message}\033[00m")


def warning(message):
    print(f"\033[93m{message}\033[00m")


def info(message):
    print(f"\033[96m{message}\033[00m")


def success(message):
    print(f"\033[92m{message}\033[00m")
```

And I have a global `imports.py` file that imports everything that I need:

```
import humps
import inflect
import json
import visitor
import logging
from message import *
error('hi')
import os
import re
import subprocess
import sys
```

And inside the `visitor.py` I import everything using `from imports import *`, and I expect to be able to use `error` function. But I get this exception:

> NameError: name 'error' is not defined. Did you mean: 'OSError'?

However, the `error('hi')` inside the `imports.py` works. But it does not work inside the `visitor.py`. What should I do?

P.S. Please do not tell me that `import *` is a bad practice, because I use Python in a simple static-code-analysis tool. It's a small project.

**Update**: This is the content inside the `visitor.py`:

```
from imports import *

def visitChildren(node, analyze):
    nodeType = type(node).__name__
    if nodeType == 'dict':
        for childNode in node:
            childNodeType = type(node[childNode]).__name__
            try:
                if (childNodeType == 'dict'):
                    analyze(node[childNode])
                visitChildren(node[childNode], analyze)
            except Exception as ex:
                error(f'\t{ex}')
    if nodeType == 'list':
        for index in range(len(node)):
            visitChildren(node[index], analyze)

def visit(path, analyze):
    if path == '':
        pass
    else:
        try:
            file = open(path)
            data = json.load(file)
            visitChildren(data, analyze)
        except Exception as ex:
            error(f'\tFile {path} has no AST or its AST can not be loaded')
            error(f'\t{ex}')
```

Comment: When `imports` is first imported (presumably by some file other than the ones you've shown), it imports `visitor` *before* it imports from `message`.  When `visitor` itself does an `import imports`, Python detects this as a circular import; what `visitor` actually gets is *the current state of `imports`*, which does not yet include anything from `message`.

Comment: "imports.py" has `import visitor` and `visitor.py` has `from imports import *` you see the cycle right?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe it is an error somewhere in the code you did not mention.
With 3 files :

user.py

```py
from intermediate import * 
message('hello, world !')
```

intermediate.py

```py
from provider import *
```

provider.py

```py
def message(s):
    print(s)
```

I get the output `hello, world !`

PS: as mentioned by @jasonharper, you also have an obvious circular import issue.